# How to animate UILabel?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uilabel

I'm using UILabel to display some dynamic text. Sometime its over lap the width of the label. I want to slide the text if the UILabel goes out of bound.

How do I do the sliding animation with UILabel? Any help?

Answer (score 3):

Modifying my answer to address the short coming pointed out -

```
UILabel *label; //Previously initialized UILabel
float newX   = 0.0;
float newY   = 101.0f;
label.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
```

If you wanted to animate the movement, it's cake to add an animation block:

```
UILabel *label; //Previously initialized UILabel
float newX = 90.0f;
float newY = 101.0f;

[UIView transitionWithView:label
                  duration:0.5f 
                   options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                animations:^(void) {
                     label.center = CGPointMake(newX, newY);
                } 
                completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                     // Do nothing
                }];
```

Notice that we only animate the X coordinate as you want the label to slide.

Comment: -1: `target_x_position` is not an `int` but a `CGFloat`. Using the `frame` instead of the `center` is error prone and not helpful.

Comment: 1. It calculates and sets position *and bounds*, which is not intended. 2. The `frame` property is only valid if there's no transform set. 3. Its use obfuscates what really shall be done.

Answer (score 0):

When I had to do something similar, I did this.
Please notice that I'm tweening the alpha, not the position, but I hope this could help you:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{yourLabel.alpha = 0.f;}];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void)repeat{


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:8.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(LabelAnimation)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];


}


-(void)LabelAnimation
{

 NSArray *elements = [yourText componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    NSMutableArray *outputElements = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int i=1;i<[elements count];i++)

            [outputElements addObject:[elements objectAtIndex:i]];


    NSString *outputString = [outputElements componentsJoinedByString:@","];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:3.0f delay:0.2f options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionNone animations:^{

        _header.labelHeaderName.text=outputString;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {
         if (outputString.length == 0) {
            _header.labelHeaderName.text=_strAddress(your saved address);
         }

     }];
    }
```